# PrintDialog parameters to PrintOut

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm creating a word add-in and I need this add-in to call a printDialog for the user to enter parameters and then to print with these parameters (number of copies, range of pages ...) 
Is there a way to easily pass all the parameters from printDialog to the printOut method?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: No, you have to pass them individually.

Comment: So I'l have to get the values from printDialog and put the corresponding values in the printOut method (I'm thinking about the range property which uses two different enum types...)?

Comment: You will have to translate the PageRange property of PrintDialog to the Range, From, To, Pages and PageType parameters.

Comment: If I use the WdDialogFilePrint instead of the PrintDialog everything print just fine but can I get the values passed to printOut (I need to get the number of copies)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using WdDialogFilePrint.
The key is to display the dialog box, then you get the values you want and execute when the user validates instead of just using the show method.